# Missing option to cancel Apple Music subscription

Tags: apple-music

I have the Apple Music 'individual' subscription, and now I want to cancel it. But when I go the the settings it does not show the option to cancel subscription.

[image]

It only gives an option to resubscribe. How can I cancel my subscription entirely?

Comment: Are you family sharing?

Comment: Yes i was using family sharing before and the subscription was not mine. But now it says it the individual subscription so i don't think the subscription is getting shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are sharing the same product with your family and friends.

Is it possible you are not actually being charged for anything and simply getting the shared benefit?

I would expect to see a checkmark icon next to the item I am responsible for.

Comment: I don't see a checkmark icon so it should be the case where i am not being charged anything

Comment: Right, probably they figured out you shouldn't;t have a cancellation subscription option either in this case. :)